# Converting PHP openssl script to openssl command

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

I'm using the following method to decrypt the data,

```
$clear = openssl_decrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $pass, 0, $iv);
```

`$iv` is always null, but it works

But when I use openssl to decrypt the same file (the data is base64 encoded),

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -in encrypted
```

After inputing the password, it says `error reading input file`, totally weird error

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you need to add the `-base64` flag?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP `$pass` is actually the full binary key. The openssl utility expects the actual password. You might want to use

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -in encrypted -K <hex-encoded key> -nosalt -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: I've tried openssl 1.1, openssl 1.0.2 and 0.9.8, none of them have the `-noiv` command line option

Comment: The $pass is a user input, e.g `abcdefg`, so PHP transformed it to binary key?

Comment: It probably silently pads it with 0x00 bytes until the key has 256 bit. In your case `abcdefg\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0`.